# how can i exchange this Quiz view for my flutter quiz app when i press the button?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, navigator

I wanna ask you about flutter.
what I want to do is make some quiz app with this class
this class is made for quiz part view.

I want to make the buttons named 'RaisedButton' are for answers and when they pressed, then changing _questionInd, the page is refreshed with the contents changing. what can I do for this goal? :(

This is for a Quiz app made by dart language and flutter framework.

```
class _SolvingPage extends MaterialPageRoute<Null> {
  int ind=0;
  int _questionInd=0;

  void _answerQuestion(){
    setState((){
      _questionInd+=1;
    });
    print(_questionInd);
  }
  _SolvingPage()
      : super(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
        'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
        'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
      },
    ];


    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('문제풀이 페이지'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
          elevation: 0.5,
          toolbarOpacity: 0.8,
          // prototype에서는 이 제목 바는 없고, 하단에 정지 아이콘을 두었음
        ),
        body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
                child: Column(
                    children:<Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                        decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          border:Border.all(width:1.5, color: Colors.white70),
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('1'),
                      ),
                      Text('1'),
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('1'),
                          onPressed:(){
                            //다음 문제로 넘어가야 함

                            int temp=_SolvingPage()._questionInd++;

                            print('$temp');

                          },
                          color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('1'),
                          onPressed:(){


                          },
                          color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('1'),
                          onPressed:(){


                          },
                          color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        //문제 넘기기 버튼, 정지 버튼
                        //문제 넘기기 버튼, 정지 버튼
                      ),
                    ]
                )

            )
        )
    );

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

화면을 바꾸기 위해서는

```
setState(() {

});
```

를 이용해야합니다

```
String quiz = "문제1";
Text(quiz);

setState(() {
  quiz = "문제2";
});
```

Comment: onPressed:(){
                          //다음 문제로 넘어가야 함
                          setState(() {
                            int temp=_questionInd++;

                            print('$temp');
                          });
                        },

Comment: onPressed 에서도 setState() 를 이용하면 클릭시 값이 변화가 되요~